# Can you help me explain this?

Tags: possessives, double-possessives

1 When I say "This is a pig's trough.", so is the word "a" describing or attached to "pig" or "trough"?

2 When I say "This is the pigs' trough.", so is the word "the" describing or attached to "pigs" or "trough"?

3 When I say "These are the women's wallets.", so is the word "the" describing or attached to "women" or "wallets"?

Thanks!

Comment: "This is a pig trough." sounds more correct to me, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As Dan said, you call the object a pig trough, so the first example would point out that the trough belongs to a pig.
The second example would point out that it belonged to several pigs.

"women's wallets", however, is like children's books or men's pants, and specify that the wallets you refer to are for women.

Comment: Thank you for your help!